# Print 10th line before a match or 10th line after a match in a list in a file, looping the last line to the first, in BASH?

Tags: bash

I have a file containing a long list of sorted and unique items, in `words.txt`:

```
apple
banana
cat
cattle
celery
cucumber
eagle
eel
fish
lion
llama
mountain lion
ostrich
pear
tomato
zebra
```

I need to print the item occurring 10 lines before a search term or the item occurring 10 lines after a search term. If it reaches the end of the file, it should continue counting from the first line in the file to find the correct match. E.g., if I searched for "fish", 10 lines before would return "tomato" and 10 lines after would return "cat".

This is what I have tried so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=`wc -l words.txt`

line="$(grep -n ^fish$ words.txt | cut -f1,1 -d:)"

echo $line

tenbefore=`expr $line - 10`
tenbefore="$(head -n "$tenbefore" words.txt)"

if [ "$tenbefore" < 1 ]
then
    tenbefore=`expr $count + $tenbefore`
    tenbefore="$(head -n "$tenbefore" words.txt)"
fi

echo $tenbefore

tenafter=`expr $line - 10`
tenafter="$(head -n "$tenafter" words.txt)"

if [ "$tenafter" > "$count" ]
then
    tenafter=`expr $tenafter - $count`
    tenafter="$(head -n "$tenafter" words.txt)"
fi

echo $tenafter
```

How can I print the 10th line before a match or the 10th line after a match, but loop the end of the file to the beginning, in situations when the 10th line before is before the first line or the 10th line after is after the last line, in BASH?

Comment: You have this tagged perl, bash, awk, sed, and grep - what are your requirements?

Answer (score 2):

If you're allowed to read the whole thing into memory, I would just do that.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n' read -r -a words -d '' <words.txt
let len=${#words[@]}
for (( i=0; i<len; ++i )); do
  if [ "${words[i]}" = fish ]; then
    echo "${words[(i+len-10)%len]}" # ten before
    echo "${words[(i+10)%len]}" # ten after
    exit 0
  fi
done
exit 1 # not found
```

You can also do it by just keeping track of the 10 most recent lines plus the first ten lines of the file, with a little fiddling.  If you're dealing with giant files, that becomes worth it/necessary, but otherwise, the straightforward solution above is a bit easier.